# Two words: Great in isolation, terrible when paired

Tags: wordplay

I have in mind two words: great in isolation, but terrible when paired.

Spoken aloud, you may be forgiven for thinking the first word is two in number. A mistake of stress.

Written down, you may be forgiven for thinking the second word is two in number. A mistake of missed keys.

(Very) cryptic clue:

> mdgf und notp df what we do in china

Hopefully not-so-cryptic clue:

> The first word is something good for engineering; the second word is something good for democracy. Also, the first "clue" is a hint at a certain webpage that contains these two words in sequence (found via Google).

Comment: Do I need to know other languages besides English to be able to solve this?

Comment: English is all that's required

Answer (score 2):

Idk about this one, but it fits.

> CELLAR, when spoken could be mistaken as "sell her"

and second

> BEDROOM, could easily be typed as bed room

because

> each one of these things is great to have, but a cellar bedroom sounds pretty terrible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a number of examples if you google

> "misplaced hyphen".

You'll find

> male + diction = malediction

or (my preferred, but not perfect for the question)

> man's + laughter = manslaughter

Comment: But how do these equate to being 'two in number' and 'mistakes of stress and missed keys'? I think those features are pretty important to finding the true words that lie at the heart of this puzzle...

Comment: Some nice examples, but ultimately not what I had in mind! I've added a hint to the problem.

Comment: I know, it only answers to the first sentence.